# Append json results to different divs

Tags: jquery, json

I got a script from a client to show some stars in the organic results from Google. 
Problem is that the script outputs the results twice. I'm pretty new to this stuff so I can't see why this is happening.

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery.ajax('http://www.shop.com/feed.php?callback=?', {
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(json){
  var reviewsHtml = [];
  $.each(json, function(index, company){
    reviewsHtml.push('<div class="stars"><div class="stars_bg"><div style="width:'+ ((company.total_score)*10) +'%" class="stars_on"></div></div></div>' + '<strong>' + company.total_score + '</strong>&nbsp;(' + company.total_reviews + '&nbsp;reviews)');
  });

  reviewsHtml = reviewsHtml.join('');

  $('#feed').html(reviewsHtml);
}
});
</script>
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="feed"></div>
```

I personally think it has something to do with reviewsHtml.join('').

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'outputs the results twice'? Within `#feed` there are two copies of the string concatenated?

Comment: @asked: Yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know why the string is being duplicated -- you might just have duplicates in your json. In any case, there is no need to buffer the results in an array. You can append them to `#feed` directly:

```
success: function(json){
    $.each(json, function(index, company){
        $('#feed').append('<div class="stars"><div class="stars_bg"><div style="width:'+ ((company.total_score)*10) +'%" class="stars_on"></div></div></div>' + '<strong>' + company.total_score + '</strong>&nbsp;(' + company.total_reviews + '&nbsp;reviews)');
    });
}
```

Comment: `.append()` will add the included html as the last child of the specified element, providing the same functionality as if you push them into an array then combined them into a string -- but it should be operationally cheaper. If you still see duplicates, the problem is in your `json`.

Comment: plus 1 for fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do this

```
$.each(json, function(index, company){
    $('#feed').append('<div class="stars"><div class="stars_bg"><div style="width:'+ ((company.total_score)*10) +'%" class="stars_on"></div></div></div>' + '<strong>' + company.total_score + '</strong>&nbsp;(' + company.total_reviews + '&nbsp;reviews)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a break in your javascript to see what that json object is returning. I would guess you may have 2 items in that json array.